# How to convert an object list from java to javascript with json

Tags: javascript, java, json, jsp

I'm trying to pass data of an object list returned from a java method with json to a function javascript on jsp class to use that variable.
I can't print it on jsp page.
Please could you give me some hints on how do this? What is the best way?

**java class**

```
import com.ibm.json.java.JSONObject;

public class test {

       public static JSONObject print() {
          JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

          obj.put("name", "foo");
          obj.put("num", new Integer(100));
          obj.put("balance", new Double(1000.21));
          obj.put("is_vip", new Boolean(true));
        return obj;
       }
}
```

**jsp class**

```
var text = test.print();

var obj = JSON.parse(text);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
obj.name + "<br>" +
obj.num + "<br>" +
obj.balance + "<br>" +
obj.is_vip;
```

Comment: You need to serialize a java object inside the java application or you need to serialize it inside the javascript code?

Comment: I need to serialize a java object inside the javascript code

Comment: Can you show us a little bit of your javascript code please?

Comment: I believe that since you are using the IBM version of JSONObject your need to call the `serialize()` method instead of the `print()` in your jsp class

Answer (score 0):

You could try using XHRequests

`var getData = function(url,callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url);
​
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        callback(xhr);
    }
​
    xhr.send(null);
};`

​Then you can call the method using something like this. (all of this goes in your .js file or inside `<script>` tags

`getData('urlTo@RequestMappingincontroller', function(xhr) {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.response < 400) {
        var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
​
        data.forEach(function(value,index,array){
            console.log(value);
        });
    }
});`